# Stop MKMapView from reloading

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, tablecell

I have a `MKMapView` with scrolling and userInteraction disabled within a `UITableViewCell`. The desired effect (effectively a static image of the map in a certain position) works really well but when the `MKMapView` drifts on and off screen (scrolling) it reloads the map, which occasionally causes the app to crash. I have loaded the custom `UITableViewCell` in like any other `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
{
    MapTableViewCell *cell = (MapTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Map", cellIdentifier]];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[MapTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MapTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (MapTableViewCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I've found out that with this current method, if you let the map image load before moving the `UITableView` then it's OK. But if you move it off the screen before it's finished loading then it will crash! :(

I will just point out that I do not want to be able to control the map in any way or show any annotations on it. I did try to screenshot a map view, hide it from screen and display that screenshot as a `UIImageView` in the `UITableViewCell` but this wasn't fast enough!

EDIT: Updated code. This is the full code for this method. Is my custom TableViewCell alloc incorrect here?

Comment: Not obvious what result you actually want to achieve. At a rough guess, if the MKMapView's delegate is the cell, you may need to un-set the delegate in the cell's -dealloc. I also can't work out what your nib-loading is supposed to do.

Comment: I've done that now thanks. Think it might have been that you know. Should I release theMapView in here too?

Comment: @tc Dealloc the cell seemed to work. Put this as an answer and I'll give you the green tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tc for the answer (the comment above).

What was required was for me to release the `MKMapView` in the custom `UITableViewCell` dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the region of the map/the scope of the map to what you are desiring and then change the properties of userInteractionEnabled and zoomEnabled. So probably something like this:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = "location";  //a CLLocationCoordinate2D location of where ever

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.03; //desired size for both latDelta and lonDelta
span.longitudeDelta = 0.03;
region.span = span;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

And then for the properties try this:

```
mapView.zoomEnabled = NO;
mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```