# MKMapView in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` in a `UITableViewCell` with user interaction disabled. When I scroll the `UITableViewCell` it refreshes all of the `MKMapViews`.

I've read the other answers on here, one says to not to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` (I'm not) and the other says to `dealloc` the `mapView` (I'm using ARC). I don't want to use images.

What should I do to prevent the `MKMapView` from reloading when I scroll my scrollview?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ANFeedCell"];
    ANFeedTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ANFeedTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];

        //Takes a center point and a span in miles (converted from meters using above method)        
        CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.766997, -122.422032);
        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startCoord, MilesToMeters(0.5f), MilesToMeters(0.5f))];
        [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];


    }
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Post your uitableviewCell drawing code, so we can see what you are doing

Comment: Added relevant code to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing NEW cells for every table cell.
So your MapView get's reset every time.

This will also lead to memory problems, as a few scrolls up & down the table, will drain your phone's memory.

Stick to reusable cells, but configure the mapview region every time for the cells.

Here is a good example to get your started:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"MyCustomTableCell";
    ANFeedTableViewCell *cell = (ANFeedTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ANFeedTableViewCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib)
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
                cell = (ANFeedTableViewCell *)oneObject;
    }



    MKMapView *mapView = (MKMapView*)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    //Takes a center point and a span in miles (converted from meters using above method)
    CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.766997, -122.422032);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(startCoord, MilesToMeters(0.5f), MilesToMeters(0.5f))];
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    return cell;
}
```

What is different in this code, is that the mapview is configured each time a cell is displayed, not only when it's initialized.
Of Course you should change the code to accept the coordinates dynamically from a datasource (i.e. a NSArray).

Comment: Perfect, been scratching my head at this for days.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a uitableview cell global object in the header file with @property and assign the cell to the global object, if the cell is nil.

Then each time you enters the cellforrowatindexpath check whether the object is nil or not.. If not nil , return the global object .

//in class.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *mapCell;
```

//in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (mapCell == nil) {
                        allocate the cell
                    }
                    else{
                        return mapCell;
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
NSArray *views = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for( int i = 0; i < [views count]; i++)
    {
        UIView *tempView = [views objectAtIndex:i];
        [tempView removeFromSuperview];
        tempView = nil;
    }

    views = nil;
```

Comment: This just removed the MKMapView.

Comment: What was required is to release the MKMapView in the custom UITableViewCell dealloc method.

Comment: I've tried setting my mapView to nil, it doesn't seem to affect whether or not it reloads on scroll.

Comment: Checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262295/stop-mkmapview-from-reloading

Comment: Already tried it out, tried everything I could find on SO. It's still happening.